# TypeScript: Object is possibly null on Union Type

Tags: typescript

I have a base interface where at least one of two properties is required.

```ts
interface Base {
    someProp: { subProp: string; } | null;
    condProp1?: boolean;
    condProp2?: boolean;
}

interface WithProp1 extends Base {
    condProp1: true;
}

interface WithProp2 extends Base {
    condProp2: true;
}

export type MyType = WithProp1 | WithProp2;
```

When I try to use `MyType` after checking that `someProp` is not null *and* after checking either `condProp1` or `condProp2` for truthiness, the compiler still thinks `someProp` might be `null`.

```ts
function doSomething(myType: MyType) {
    if (myType.someProp && (
        myType.condProp1 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'foo' ||
        myType.condProp2 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'bar')) {
        console.log("It's true, isn't it?  It's really true.");
    }
}
```

In `doSomething()`, `myType.someProp.subProp` is giving a compile-time error saying that `someProp` might be `null`.  This doesn't happen if I replace `MyType` with `Base` in the function signature.

```ts
// Compiles fine
function doSomethingBase(myType: Base) {
    if (myType.someProp && (
        myType.condProp1 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'foo' ||
        myType.condProp2 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'bar')) {
        console.log("It's true, isn't it?  It's really true.");
    }
}
```

Switching the order to `myType.someProp.subProp === 'foo' && myType.condProp1` works as a workaround for the first line, but not the second.  Any idea why this happens or how to get around it (I can use a `!` but I shouldn't have to)?  Seems like a bug in the compiler.

I'm using TSC version 3.5.3.  [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChkHIYD2AthAApTEAOAXMtkQK4BGVtDGYUoA5gG5kAX2QAfZCGYAbaQPyEExEABMONAIwB+Bq2LFpEOCHmFkS1eoBMO5HoNGTuYblyhIsRCgDqwMAAt1DWQIAA9IVQw0TBwFAgs1ak0GHmYIeRc3cGh4JGRfAOsQ8IhI6KxGOPNlRNorFKg0jNcwmmIoMGQwAE8aFABZboAVXpQAXny-QKTgiQLpuvlcGGYQBDBgZWQVYgBlMggA-gAKUmHRhkGRvoBKSrNgGGRT876AOhJydWQAMh-nqpmM7XCAfA7qD5sb5jGHIADkMH0cN+-2BozeCSC4jEgMIaPemKSVhRyHxoM+lCSkPYSWQMImcNYcCgcJudzwZjMFhIhje0mIfGOACIAJJgOFRVIQAA0yGAGBAcM6fi0BDFEuQUCMsm6XUaoKFN1MhBcmRWaw2Wx2+3IRxAfHQWBeIIYjog7Kqj2eZLBX1pfwBnLxr1BhNowQDPopEIwUNp9PhiOIyLEOKDBB9YZoxMjId9lNo1OhsMZzNZHvT1RAPNB-MFovFkv1svliuVYFVyHVUS1cB1erSb0NxoIpqAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this actually is a compiler bug; I don't know the internals intimately enough to say, but I suspect that the compiler is evaluating the initial guard clause as type `Base`, and then the inner clauses as `WithPropX`, and is losing the information that myType as `WithPropX` has already been guarded against a null someProp.

You can work around this by inverting the order of the checks, so the more specific type inference happens earlier in the condition (and then the someProp null check is happening at the point that the compiler knows that myType is a `WithPropX`, rather than a `Base`):

```
function doSomething(myType: MyType) {
    if (myType.condProp1 && myType.someProp && myType.someProp.subProp === 'foo' ||
        myType.condProp2 && myType.someProp && myType.someProp.subProp === 'bar') {
        console.log("It's true, isn't it?  It's really true.");
    }
}
```

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24091) seems like it may be related to what you're observing here.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Chris Helad said:

> I suspect that the compiler is evaluating the initial guard clause as type Base, and then the inner clauses as WithPropX, and is losing the information that myType as WithPropX has already been guarded against a null someProp.

So, compiler, probably, works like that:

```js
function doSomething(myType: MyType) {
  if (myType.someProp && ( // myType is type of WithProp1 | WithProp2 AND someProp is defined
    myType.condProp1 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'foo' || // condProp1 is defined, so, myType is typeof WithProp1 (forgot that someProp is defined)
    myType.condProp2 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'bar')) { // condProp2 is defined, so, myType is typeof WithProp2 (forgot that someProp is defined)
    console.log(`It's true, isn't it?  It's really true.`);
  }
}
```

To beat it you could define a simple [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to tell the compiler about the actual type:

```js
function hasProp(t: MyType): t is MyType & {someProp: NonNullable<MyType['someProp']>} {
  return !!t.someProp;
}

function doSomething(myType: MyType) {
  if (hasProp(myType) && (
    myType.condProp1 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'foo' ||
    myType.condProp2 && myType.someProp.subProp === 'bar')) {
    console.log(`It's true, isn't it?  It's really true.`);
  }
}
```